# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null

Tags: multithreading, powershell, temporary-files

```
(1, 2, 3) | ForEach-Object {
    Start-ThreadJob {
        $TempIn = New-TemporaryFile
        ('1', '1', '2', '3') | Out-File $TempIn.FullName -Encoding ascii
    }
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Running the above minimum example triggers the "Open with" prompt (even though nowhere am I telling it to open the temporary file) and the following error for every iteration:

```
Out-File:
Line |
   3 |          ('1', '1', '2', '3') | Out-File $TempIn.FullName -Encodi …
     |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
```

Comment: Sounds like something got corrupted on your machine, like `New-TemporaryFile`. If so,  you'll see the symptom also without `Start-ThreadJob` in the picture.

Comment: @mklement0 hmm.. could be a Temp folder permission issue.. Not getting any errors without `Start-ThreadJob` though. I'll try in a VM. Are you unable to reproduce?

Comment: Interesting. The error only happens if I run the script in Powershell 7 (should've probably noted from the get-to that that's what I'm using). It runs fine in 5.1, after installing the `ThreadJob` module which AFAIK comes preinstalled in 7.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? I just tested your snippet in Pwsh 7.2.3 and it ran as expected.

Comment: You're right! It is working now. I guess Windows has just been throwing a tantrum for a couple days?